# Unable to use URL as filename in python

Tags: python, url, file-io, io

I'm trying to use url as a filename for a file that is generated from my python script.
But when I try to do that it return the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "webdriver_adhoc_crawler1.py", line 36, in <module>
fo = io.open('%s' % line, 'w+', encoding='utf8')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.google.com'
```

The error occurs at this line :

```
line="http://www.google.com"
fo = io.open('%s' % line, 'w+', encoding='utf8')
```

How do i fix this issue ? Or is it even possible to use url as a filename in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Filenames cannot contain these characters: `\/:*?"<>|`, so therefore your program is unable to find/create this file, and, it throws an error.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open a webpage, you can use "urllib2" to get the webpage.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
html = response.read()
```